# Dimension of $F[x]/I$ where $I$ is ideal generated by irreducible polynomial of degree $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that $\dim F[x]/(p(x)) = \deg p(x)$, where $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ and $( p(x))$ is the ideal generated by $p(x)$.

First I want to know what is means for $\dim F[x]/(p(x))$. I know $F[x]$ is a vector space over $F$. If $p(x)$ is irreducible, then $I = (p(x))$ is a maximal ideal therefore $F[x]/I$ is a field. I'm thinking that $\dim F[x]/(p(x))$ means dimension of $F[x]/I$ as a vector space over $F$.

If so, then by Euclidean algorithm, all elements in $F[x]/I$ can be written as $[q(x)]$ where $q(x)$ is of degree less than $p(x)$. Then doesn't it mean that $\dim F[x]/I = \deg p(x) -1$?

I'm new to the topic, so please correct my mistake and point me towards a proof. Thanks.

Comment: Your second paragraph is correct.  The only idea you're missing is that we can consider polynomials $q(x)$ of degree 0, that is, constants.  This adds one more basis vector, which makes the degree of the extension equal to the degree of $p(x)$.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is perfect. It’s just your counting that was off.

Comment: @Jared I see now. Could you please shift your comment to answer and add the isomorphism map $\Phi:F[x]/I\to F_{p-1}[x]$ with $\Phi([s(x)]) = s(x)$ where $s(x)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $p-1$? I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.  Your argument shows that every element in $F[x]/I$ can be represented by a polynomial of degree $< n := \deg(p(x))$.  Use this to argue that the $n$ (not $n-1$) elements $1 \pmod{I}, x \pmod{I}, \dots, x^{n-1} \pmod{I}$ span $F[x]/I$ as an $F$-vector space.

Then you must show that these $n$ elements are linearly independent over $F$, which can be done by directly applying the definition of linear independence and using the fact that $p(x)$ is an element of minimal degree in $I = \langle p(x) \rangle$.

Comment: I have another way, I define $\Phi:F[x]/I\to F_{p-1}[x]$ where $F_{p-1}[x]$ is polynomial of degree $< p$ and show this is an isomorphism of vector spaces. Is it fine?

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly fine, though your notation is non-standard.  (It is easy to get $F_{p-1}[x]$ confused with $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, which is used to denote the ring of all polynomials with coefficients in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$.)

Comment: Would proving $\Phi$ being a bijection and homomorphism suffice to show it is an isomorphism?

Comment: The map $\Phi$ is not a (ring) homomorphism!  More to the point, the set $F_{p-1}[x]$ is not a ring, because multiplication is not defined on it.  What you should do is show that $\Phi$ is a bijective linear transformation.

Comment: I think I used the wrong word, I meant to say that if $\Phi(av+bu) = a\Phi(v)+b\Phi(u)$ plus it is bijective is it enough to be an isomorphism of vector fields?

Comment: Yes, that's all you need. :)